# Cannot install A.L.F.R.E.D on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: networking, pi-2

I am trying to work with adhoc networks and I am using the **batman-adv** which is available in the Kernel.

I am currently using a **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with 1 GB RAM** with **Debian Wheezy version 7.8**

I want to use the [A.L.F.R.E.D](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/alfred/wiki) from the same guys who made **B.A.T.M.A.N** to get local information from the Raspberry Pi in a adhoc fashion

I have cloned the repository and try to `make` but it keeps giving me an error of **no libcap development libraries found. Stop!**

I tried downloading the `libcap-dev` using :

```
apt-get install libcap-dev
```

and then try to `make` again. But it still keeps giving me the same error.

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://cccfr.de/wiki/freifunk:alfred&prev=search) badly translated page seems to suggest that this may be a bug. The fix provided is:

```
dirty solution: in the Makefile left put on libcap and ifeq loop uncomment

  (Endig ifeq ....) # comment out # line 84 till line 91
 LDLIBS + = # Replace line 28 -lrt -lpcap -lcap # existing line with this 

then

  make install
```

These instructions may be more coherent with a better translation!

Comment: thanks @goobering . luckily I can understand german. Will have a look and solve this. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it. :) If you feel the question's been sufficiently answered, I'd appreciate the upvote.

Comment: I tried sadly I have only 11 reps. need more reps to give you an upvote.

Comment: [You can always accept an answer to your own question.](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Don't worry about it if it's not working. There's an [easy bronze badge](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed) for scanning the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) pages here, full of good stuff for getting started.

Comment: have you worked with ALFRED before? do you know a good manual on how to run Slave mode in ALFRED on Pis?

Comment: No on all counts I'm afraid! I'm just handy with Google.